# How to enforce deriving classes to implement an abstract property but allow implementations to use child classes of the type?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I am trying to enforce all classes deriving from class EducationalUnit to implement a "Content" property. This property needs to be a key value pair where the key is an int and the value can be either another class implementing EducationalUnit or another class I have called ContentBlock.

in EducationalUnit class i try to define an abstract property to take an Int and any Object key value pair.

`public abstract Dictionary<int, Object> Content {get; set;}`

And in the inheriting classes try to implement it:

```
public class Course : EducationalUnit
    {
        public override Dictionary<int, EducationalUnit> Content {get; set;}
    
        public Course () {
            this.Type = "Course";
        }
    }
```

However, when I try to do this I get 'Course.Content': type must be 'Dictionary<int, object>' to match overridden member 'EducationalUnit.Content' [Domain]csharp(CS1715).

I assumed since all classes inherit from Object this should have worked. Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong and a potential approach to implement this?

Comment: Do you not get a warning when you compile that the property should either be marked as `override` or `new`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-define-abstract-properties

Comment: "I assumed since all classes inherit from Object this should have worked" - it's a two-way street - you can't assign just any `Object` value to a `Dictionary<int, EducationalUnit>`, so it can't stand in for a `Dictionary<int, Object>`

Comment: If this was allowed, someone would be able to do `var course = new Course(); ((EducationUnit)course).Content[3] = "Hello";`. Now accessing `course.Content[3]` will be a string, but `EducationUnit.Content` is a `Dictionary<int, EducationalUnit>` and should only be returning an `EducationUnit`! That's a big problem, which is why it's forbidden.

Comment: Apologies, edited my question - the override issue I already solved, the error is now adjusted in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot override the type `Dictionary<int, Object>` with `Dictionary<int, EducationalUnit>`.

You could define a generic though, and make it work that way.

```cs
abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
    public abstract Dictionary<int, T> Content { get; set; }
}

class EducationalUnit { }

class Course : BaseClass<EducationalUnit>
{
    public override Dictionary<int, EducationalUnit> Content { get; set; } = new();

    public Course() 
    { }    
}
```

You could also override it with `public override Dictionary<int, object> Content { get; set; } = new();`, but then you can't access any of the variables, properties or methods you have on `EducationalUnit`, unless you cast it back to an `EducationalUnit` from `object`. But this really defeats the purpose of using inheritance.

Comment: I think this is the way to go, you might also want to constrain the generic `BaseClass<T>` though with something like `where T : ContentBaseClass`